# How to bypass hourly limit of outgoing messages?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, asus-zenfone-2

How do one bypass hourly limit of 100 outgoing SMS on Android 6 without replacing completely current system provided by OEM?

Comment: Might be related: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/38468/5342

Comment: Maybe rebooting the device resets counter?

Comment: @geffchang Related but not applicable to Marshmallow

Comment: @ballzak Rebooting imply missing messages  and draining the battery very quickly in addition to unproven results (maybe).